# SQL query into outfile csv:

Tags: sql, oracle, file

I am running the following query, which works fine on its own (the first line below), but which I now want to export into a csv file:

```
select * from my_table where column1 = 'asdf' and column2 = 'qwer'

into OUTFILE 'test.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

The error I receive is:

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

How can I fix this so that my original query can go into test.csv?

Comment: I'm not Oracle expert, but I believe `INTO OUTFILE` syntax is mysql syntax, not Oracle. I believe Oracle SQLPlus (as an example client) uses  `SPOOL filename...SPOOL OFF` type syntax.

Comment: Oh I have no idea, I haven't used any type of sql in ages. Thanks I'll look into that.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not provide outfile option. Your requirement can be fulfilled with the below sample code:

```
set pages 0
spool test.csv
select * from my_table where column1 = 'asdf' and column2 = 'qwer';
spool off
```